# Return value in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How to describe a function in an interface, in whose signature the return type is the interface itself. I suppose that there is a way, to solve it, as it is in other languages.

```clj
(definterface Expression
  (^Number evaluate [data])
  (^Expression diff [diffVar]))
```

```
Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling deftype* at (expressionJava.clj:8:1).
java.lang.Expression

Full report at:
/var/folders/38/5xvf_2f13fbd4lfxg89f42x00000gn/T/clojure-7914023953805611339.edn
```

I'd tried to "declare Expreesion", but ain't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(definterface Expression
    (evaluate ^Number [data])
    (diff ^Expression [diffVar]))
```

In Clojure, return type hints are metadata on the argument list, not on the function name.

Comment: P.S. Alex Miller gave the [Java Interop Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_xjnXB994w) talk which covers this topic as well.